# Jquery Defer & Each Loop

Tags: jquery, promise, getjson, jquery-deferred

I'm a bit new to JSON and Deferrers, so apologies it the answer is obvious.

I am working with the pokeapi.co and I am trying to pull out details of various pokemon using getJSON. I created a function which takes an array of URLs, runs a getJSON function to pull the data from the URLs, iterate over the data and push it into an array. I am trying to use the defer object and promises to determine when all that has been done so I can use the data in another function. Unfortunately, I seem to be doing something wrong.

```
var url = [
  "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/",
  "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
];

function getPokemonDetails(url){
  var def = $.Deferred();
  var promises = [];
  var pokemon;
  $.each(url, function(i, index){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON(index, function(data){
      pokemon = [data.name, data.stats];
      var abilityURLs = [];
      $.each(data.abilities, function(a, abilities){
        abilityURLs.push(abilities.ability.url)
      });

      pokemon.push(abilityURLs);
      deferred.resolve(pokemon);
    }); //End getJSON

    deferred.done(function(data){
      promises.push(data);
      console.log(promises);
    })// End Deferred
  }); //End Each

  $.when(...promises).done(function(){
    console.log(arguments.length);
  });
}

getPokemonDetails(url);
```

At the moment, when the console.log runs, I am expecting the length of the promises array to be 2, but at the moment it returns 0. I am not sure exactly where I went wrong.

Comment: When creating an array of promises, .map is usually the right tool. You need the array of promises immediately, which is part of your problem; you aren't pushing to the array until the promise is done, which is incorrect.

Comment: and when using `$.getJSON` it's usually an anti-pattern to create your own jQuery deferred objects around them

Comment: Additionally, you don't need `$.Deferred`, $.getJSON already returns a promise.

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, instead of using `$.each` and a push, since you have a 1:1 mapping from source array to destination array, you should use `Array.prototype.map`.

Secondly, since `$.getJSON` already returns a `$.Deferred()` there's absolutely no need to create one of your own.

So, if I follow your current code correctly, it can be replaced completely with this:

```
function getPokemonDetails(url_list) {
    return $.when(... url_list.map(url =>
        $.getJSON(url).then(
            data => [ data.name, data.stats, [
                data.abilities.map(ability => ability.ability.url)
            ]]
        )
    ));
}
```

The inner `.then` call takes the data returned from each AJAX call and returns a promise that resolves to the array of name, stats and nested array of abilities.

For what it's worth, I would probably however split this into two functions - one that handles a single URL, and another that can handle multiple ones:

```
const getPokemonDetails = url => $.getJSON(url).then(
    data => [ data.name, data.stats, [
                data.abilities.map(ability => ability.ability.url)
            ]]);

const getMultiPokemonDetails = list => $.when(...list.map(getPokemonDetails));
```

Comment: HI Alnitak, thanks for your reply. the three dots before the url_list in your solution, is that an array spread operator? I thought they had to be right next to the array?

Comment: @tcherokee Yes, it's an array spread operator, and the white space is legal

Comment: Hi Alnitak, apologies for not replying for a while, I've been doing some research and reading to fully understand your solution. It uses a few ideas I hadn't gotten around to learning yet (arrow functions for example). So I have a few questions. one, for some reason, the solution above only shows one result, even though two URLs get passed into the url_list. I am not sure why. Second question, if I expand the above function (i.e. `url_list.map(function(){...})` as opposed to `url_list.map(url=>...`, it stops working. I was hoping you would know why?

Comment: @tcherokee the returned promise _should_ give two results `getPokemonDetails(list).then(function(result1, result2) { ... }`.  ( `$.when` doesn't generate an array).   As for the arrow functions, don't forget that a single-expression arrow function has an implicit `return`, so if not using that syntax you must _explicitly_ `return` the desired result.

Comment: I think I have everything as it should be. I added all the working data into a pen so you could take a look. https://codepen.io/tcherokee/pen/jwZPej

Comment: @tcherokee you're getting there, but I see a few minor issues, like for example where you end up storing a promise in the fourth element of the array instead of the return values from that promise.  In `getPokemonAbility` you `.map` over multiple values, but you don't "spread" those array values into `$.when`.  Consider using `Promise.all([ array ])` instead of `$.when(p1, p2, ...)`

Comment: also the final data you write to the console (since you're using `$.when`) should be all the function parameters (accessed via `arguments`) and not just the single `data` parameter.   This is again somewhere where `Promise.all` might help.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Alnitak, I've gotten it working now and I've updated the codepen with the working code. Let me know what you think of my code.

Comment: it's getting better - there's no need for the `Promise.resolve()` call, nor the outer `$.when()` at the bottom.